# Will the Christians know when the Second Coming is near?

Tags: eschatology, second-coming

According to the following verse, the Christians will know that the Second Coming is near when specific events happen:

> ‘so likewise ye, when ye shall see all these things, know that it is near, even at the doors.’ - [‭‭Matthew‬ ‭24‬:‭33‬ ‭KJV‬‬](https://bible.com/bible/1/mat.24.33.KJV)

On the other hand, the following verse states that the Second Coming will be at an unexpected moment:

> ‘Therefore be ye also ready: for in such an hour as ye think not the Son of man cometh.’ - ‭‭[Matthew‬ ‭24‬:‭44‬ ‭KJV‬‬](https://bible.com/bible/1/mat.24.44.KJV)

Do these verses contradict each other?
Note that they are in the same chapter.

Comment: No. It is said that "no man knows the day nor the hour."

Comment: **The Space in Between** There are several verses between vs. 33 and vs. 44 that make all the difference in the world!  They are *transition* verses that change topics from the End of Judea to the End of the World. Thus there is not the slightest contradiction! Good question provides opportunity to clear up many people's confusion about the Olivet Discourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction because there is a dividing line between verse 34 and verse 35.  The first section (3-34) deals with Jesus "coming" to destroy the Temple, and the second section (verse 35ff) deals with the Second "Coming" at the end of the world.  The first deals with "days" (plural), and the second deals with "the Day"
(singular)!

The contrary conjunction "but" emphasizes contrast (Gk.).  The first section gives many signs leading up to the destruction of Judea (and the Temple), but the second section strongly emphasizes "no signs" (no warning).  No doubt Jesus anticipated the flurry of prognosticators who would write books playing on the fears and curiosity of believers, so he gave several illustrations to emphasize His point:  **no signs**.

Modern propheteers (sic) mistakenly enumerate the evil conducts of Noah's day, as if that is what Jesus is talking about.  They err.  Jesus gave his own interpretation of what He was trying to say:  **they didn't know!**  No signs warned them of the time of the end.  Modernists err by not reading the whole verse but stopping in mid-stream.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 4):

The New Testament is written in such a way that every generation of Christians must be expecting Christ's return within their lifetime. Yet they are simultaneously taught from scripture that many will die before that event:

> "But I would not have you to be ignorant, brethren, concerning them
> which are asleep [in death], that ye sorrow not, even as others which
> have no hope. For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even
> so them also which sleep in Jesus will God bring with him. For this we
> say unto you by the word of the Lord, that we which are alive and
> remain unto the coming of the Lord shall not prevent them which are
> asleep. For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout,
> with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God: and the
> dead in Christ shall rise first. Then we which are alive and remain
> shall be caught up together with them in them clouds, to meet the Lord
> in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord." 1 Thessalonians
> 4:13-17

The apostle John remained alive until Christ appeared to him in visions to show the build-up of world events and plagues from heaven to climax with Satan's greatest deception over all the inhabitants of Earth. Those latter days will be cut short so that the elect will not be deceived - Matthew 24:22-24, cf. Revelation 13:13-15 which shows that many faithful Christians at that time will be killed by satanic world powers.

The book of the Revelation enlarges on Jesus' signs in Matthew chapter 24, so that all Christians ought to know the nearness of Christ's return. What helps is that Christ listed as 'no-signs', wars, false Christs, famines, pestilences and earthquakes. Those things have always occurred, but it will take much more than that to combine for the pen-ultimate event.

When Jesus used the phrase, "a ***beginning*** of sorrows" in 24:8, ***the Greek for 'birth-pangs' is in the text.*** A women approaching the time to give birth knows what that means. All mothers know that, at the start of this time, the pains are slight and well spaced out, but as the hours go by, they get more severe and more frequent until, shortly before the birth, they are incessant and almost unbearable. When the first pangs start, she cannot know how long it will be till the point of birth arrives. She will be able to carry on doing whatever she's doing with no sense of urgency until many hours have passed. Rarely, a woman comes to the point of birth in just two or three hours. It can actually take more than a day with some women. So, there is no telling, but no expectant mother noticing the first slight contractions will ignore them! She knows the inevitable conclusion, and must brace herself once the signs become intense.

So with Christians noticing the combination of signs that are more than what 'normally' happens in history. The book of the Revelation is Jesus' message to prepare his Church so that whenever he returns, they will have remained faithful, even to death or till his sudden appearing in glory. In every century since he returned to heaven, many of those prophesied events in Revelation have been experienced by the Church, especially persecution and being killed for bearing Christ's name. But there are seven last plagues and three woes for the Earth that are outstanding. Careful study of the whole Revelation is vital and I recommend this 600+ page exposition, *"The Revelation of Jesus Christ"* by John Metcalfe http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

**All those Christians who have not been deceived by the final satanic deception, but who recognise it for what it is, will know that Christ is on the brink of appearing.** They will know they have to stand fast in faith, even to the point of death, or until Christ spectacularly appears to raise the faithful dead and have them join them in the sky.

So, **there is no contradiction between Matthew 24:33 & 44**. Jesus made both statements because he warned of the danger of some believers being deceived (vs. 4), and others so busy enjoying themselves that, as it was in the days of Noah, they will take no note until its too late (vss. 36-44). Revelation fills in the gaps with much more detail, which Jesus gave to enable Christians in every generation to remain faithful. “Blessed is he who reads, and they that hear the words of this prophecy, and keep those things which are written herein” (Rev. 1:3) but how many Christians do that with respect to Christ’s prophecy of Revelation?

Comment: +1 @Anne I really like this answer. I started a subreddit at reddit.com/r/BibleVerseCommentary. Can I copy your answer here and share it with the members of my subreddit? Of course, I will attribute the post to your name and hermeneutics.stackexchange.com :) –

Comment: @Tony Chan  I've never looked at Reddit before, so had a look just now. Having had a look, Reddit is not a site that I would personally be happy with. Further, I'm also afraid your idea will violate Stack Exchange 'rules' about copyright, so I will decline permission regarding this. Sorry to disappoint on this occasion.

Comment: No worries. God bless :)

Answer (score 3):

The great final "synoptic apocalypse" (Matt 24, 25, Mark 13, Luke 21) should always seen as a whole as it consists of seven warning "signs" and seven warning parables.

The seven warning parables provide a subtlety different warning message for each as follows:

- Warning Parable #1: Fig Tree, Matt 24:32-35; this tells us to be ready when the warning signs are seen
- Warning Parable #2: Noah & Flood, Matt 24:36-41; this tells us that the wicked, by contrast with the righteous, will be completely ignorant of the immanent arrival of Jesus up to the final day
- Warning Parable #3: Thief, Matt 24:42-44; this tells us that we need to be prepared at all times and spiritually protect ourselves at all times
- Warning Parable #4: Servant, Matt 24:45-51; this tells us to remain active and obedient until the Lord returns (see also Matt 21:28-32)
- Warning Parable #5: Ten Virgins, Matt 25:1-13; this tells us to have plenty of "oil", ie, the Holy Spirit to provide spiritual illumination (John 16:13, 14)
- Warning Parable #6: Talents, Matt 25:14-30; this tells us to use our God-given gifts for the service of the master
- Warning Parable #7: Sheep and Goats, Matt 25:31-46; this tells us that there is a final judgement that separates the righteous from the wicked and how the two groups are distinguished

Thus, the distinction between Matt 24:33 vs 44 becomes rather simple

- V33 tells us that we can be encouraged when we see the warnings signs and to know that Jesus return is near
- V44 tells us that we cannot know the exact time of Jesus return but it could be anytime and thus we must be constantly ready.

Comment: @Dottard-The list of the last Six Warnings about there being NO SIGNS is right on! They all refer to the signless **Second Coming**. The first in your list, however, is separated from the others by verse 34. The signs previously listed refer to the **Destruction of Judea**. *I tell you the truth, this generation (30-70 years) will certainly not pass away until all these things will have happened.*  Without recognizing the transition *by Jesus* from the End of Jerusalem, to the End of the World there is a misappropriation of "signs" at the Second Coming. Consider again, verse 34.  Peace.

Comment: @raygrant - I fully agree that much of what Jesus said in Matt 24 applies to the destruction of Jerusalem.  The sermon exists in two halves - seven warning signs (V4-31) followed by seven warning parables, V32 to 25:46.  At the same time, the destruction of Jersualem is used to teach about the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus gave some obvious signs in Matthew 24.

> And as he sat upon the mount of Olives, the disciples came unto him privately, saying, Tell us, when shall these things be? and what shall be the sign of thy coming, and of the end of the world?
>
> And Jesus answered and said unto them, Take heed that no man deceive you.
> For many shall come **in my name, saying, I am Christ**; and shall deceive many.
> And ye shall hear of **wars and rumours of wars**: see that ye be not troubled: for all these things must come to pass, but the end is not yet.
> For nation shall rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom: and there shall be **famines**, and **pestilences, and earthquakes**, in divers places.
>
> All these are the beginning of sorrows.
> Then shall they deliver you up to be afflicted, and shall kill you: and ye shall be hated of all nations for my name's sake.
> And then shall many be offended, and shall betray one another, and shall hate one another.
> And many false prophets shall rise, and shall deceive many.
>
> And because iniquity shall abound, the love of many shall wax cold.
> But he that shall endure unto the end, the same shall be saved.
> And this gospel of the kingdom shall be preached in all the world for a witness unto all nations; and then shall the end come.
> — Matthew 24: 3–14

The highlighted points correspond to the four horsemen of Revelation 6 (White: false christs; Red: wars; Black: famine; Pale: death).
(Which sounds remarkably like a description of the current world news.)

Many organizations publish lists of signs of Jesus's return.
Here are a couple of examples:

- [Seven Prophetic Signs Before Jesus Returns | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/seven-prophetic-signs-before-jesus-returns)
- [Fourteen Signs Announcing Christ's Return | Living Church of God](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/booklets/fourteen-signs-announcing-christs-return/content)

When one sees those signs happening, one knows it's near.

But just because something is certain to happen soon, that doesn't mean that anyone can know exactly when.
(Imagine a Jenga tower that's starting to sway a little. You *know* it's going to fall, but when it does it's still a surprise.)

Comment: The Jenga tower argument is very enlightening!

Comment: However, I find those signs to be very confusing, since there have been wars, pestilences, famines and earthquakes for two thousand continuous years

Comment: @Riemann, yes, but they have been localized events. Verses 21 and 22 say:
"*For then shall be great tribulation, such as was **not since the beginning of the world** to this time, no, nor ever shall be.
And except those days should be shortened, **there should no flesh be saved**: but for the elect's sake those days shall be shortened.*".
Has there ever been a time in history when *all of mankind* faced death?
We've just seen how quickly and how far a disease outbreak can spread.
Then consider "modern" weapons of war: nuclear, biological, chemical, etc.

Comment: @Riemann, also, until very recently the idea of 200,000,000 soldiers (Revelation 9:16) could be seen only as fantasy or hyperbole. But now it is actually a realistic figure, especially given that India and China seem to be forging closer ties lately. That's well under 10% of their total population, and other eastern countries could join the coalition (e.g. Russia and Japan).  Compare with WWI, where in Newfoundland, 35 percent of men aged 19 to 35 served in the military.

Comment: I think that our current time is not worse than earlier moments in history. For example, many more people died from the Spanish Flu than from Covid-19. However, if there will be a worldwide nuclear war then that would be the greatest tribulation ever.

Comment: @Riemann, the two key things are that until recently there has never been a time when a 200 million army was possible (world population was under a billion until the 20th century, now it's nearly ten times that), and there has never been a time where diseases etc. could kill *everyone* on Earth (international flights now make the spread easy and inevitable).

Answer (score 0):

Many do not take the time to consider and to understand that there two "comings" of our Lord spoken of in the New Testament.  For example, he is said to come "as a thief in the night" (1 Thessalonians 5:2; 2 Peter 3:10) and he is also said to come "with a shout, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God" (1 Thessalonians 4:16) and "with clouds; and every eye shall see him" (Revelation 1:7).

Thieves in the night do not announce their arrival--secrecy is their mission, which is why they come in the cover of darkness.

So the Lord is obviously addressing two separate events here.  There are two "comings": his coming in judgment, and his coming in glory.

In Matthew 24, both comings get some attention, but it is the coming in judgment that gets more of Jesus' focus.  This is because if we are not ready to be judged, we will not be ready for his "second coming" when he comes in glory.  (Note that the expression "second coming" is not in the Bible.)

In verse 33, Jesus is addressing his coming in glory--as we can see from verse 30, just prior:

> And then shall appear the sign of the Son of man in heaven: and then
> shall all the tribes of the earth mourn, and they shall see the Son of
> man coming in the clouds of heaven **with power and great glory.**
> (Matthew 24:30, KJV)

But in verse 44, Jesus is referencing his coming in judgment--when the cases of all will be decided, and their probation closed.  Jesus shifted between the two at verse 36.

> But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven,
> but my Father only. (Matthew 24:36, KJV)

Not even the angels will know of this coming--and Mark 13:32 adds Jesus, the Son of Man, to the "ignorant" list.

> But of that day and that hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels which
> are in heaven, neither the Son, but the Father. (Mark 13:32, KJV)

Why would Jesus not know the time of his coming?  Indeed, this is not referring to his coming--but to the close of probation; we could say it is his coming in judgment.

To illustrate this, Jesus refers to the story of the Flood.  But he doesn't tell the whole story.  The Jews of his day would have had it memorized, and did not need all of the details.  For us, it helps to look back to Genesis to fill in the blanks.

> **In the selfsame day entered Noah**, and Shem, and Ham, and Japheth, the
> sons of Noah, and Noah's wife, and the three wives of his sons with
> them, into the ark; . . . And they that went in, went in male and
> female of all flesh, as God had commanded him: **and the LORD shut him
> in.** (Genesis 7:13-16, KJV)

Jesus refers to this "day", saying: "until **the day** that Noe entered into the ark," (Matthew 24:38) and goes on to say the people "knew not until the flood came, and took them all away; so shall also the coming of the Son of man be." (vs. 39).

What didn't they know?  They didn't know that when that door had been shut, their probation had closed.  Had the flood already come?  No.  Again, we refer to Genesis...

> For yet **seven days**, and I will cause it to rain upon the earth forty
> days and forty nights; and every living substance that I have made
> will I destroy from off the face of the earth. (Genesis 7:4, KJV)

After that door had been shut, there were yet seven days until the flood came.  During those seven days, the people, not knowing that they had already been judged and their probation had already closed, carried on as usual--eating, drinking, marrying, and giving in marriage.  Until the flood came.  That is when they knew.

When Jesus comes in glory it will be too late for those who were not prepared at his coming in judgment.  If, when their cases are decided in heaven, they are found wanting, the coming in glory will be to their shame.

Will we know when Jesus' coming is near?  Yes.  But we will never know when our case is brought to judgment in heaven *before* that coming.  And it is the first coming--that of judgment--that is the most critical.  If we do not pass the test, we do not graduate later.

Comment: "Many do not take the time to consider and to understand that there two "comings" of our Lord spoken of in the New Testament." This needs to be rephrased. People can come to different conclusions about the scriptures through careful reading, and not just because they aren't taking enough time to consider and understand properly.

Comment: "*So the Lord is obviously addressing two separate events here.*" Not necessarily. They could just be descriptions of the same event from two different perspectives. From the perspective of those without faith in Christ, His coming is like a thief in the night because they will be judged unexpectedly, while from the perspective of the saved, it is a glorious and magnificent event, because they are transformed into an immortal and imperishable state to be with Christ (in fact, this is what 1 Thess. 4 says in v.14-17). It doesn't have to mean that Christ will come two separate times.

Comment: How can you say that His coming is not as a thief in the night for those with faith? In Matthew 24:44, Jesus is speaking to the disciples

Comment: His coming as a thief in the night is to everyone--faith or no faith.  This is attested by both Peter and Paul; and confirms what Jesus himself taught as recorded in Matthew 12:37-40, the last two verses of which say: _" And this know, that if the goodman of the house had known what hour the thief would come, he would have watched, and not have suffered his house to be broken through. Be ye therefore ready also: for the Son of man cometh at an hour when ye think not."_ (Matthew 12:39-40, KJV)

Comment: Coming "as a thief in the night" (1 Thessalonians 5:2; 2 Peter 3:10) and coming "with a shout, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God" (1 Thessalonians 4:16) and "with clouds; and every eye shall see him" (Revelation 1:7) are fully compatible! The "shout", "the voice of the archangel", and "the trump of God" may perfectly start to sound all of a sudden, without any forewarning!

Comment: @Johannes When is the last time you saw a thief come that way?

Comment: The "thief" metaphor refers to the unexpected character of the event. BTW, an armed thief will of course enter the house silently and unexpectedly, but once he is in, he will usually turn on the lights, wake the family up, compel them at gunpoint to give him the key to the safe-deposit box (or the location of money and jewels if they do not have a safe-deposit box), and lock them inside a closet.

Comment: @Johannes The context of Matthew 24:36-44 clearly indicates that "the day" and "hour" referred to which no one will know, not even Jesus per Mark 13:32, will be point in time when the door is shut, i.e. probation has closed. No one will know that his or her case has been already decided--even as the antediluvians were oblivious _until the flood came_, at which point they knew. This coming in judgment is the coming as a thief. The thief metaphor is important--anyone misunderstanding it will be the more surprised when they finally "know" (when it's already too late). Thieves come unannounced.

Answer (score 0):

the scripture states no man knoweth the day nor the hour, but to the believers maybe the week or the month or possibly the year according to signs... but to be truthful it is more beneficial to be prepared than to set your chronograph

Answer (score 0):

No, Christians today will not see a "second" coming of Christ, because the "second coming" or second appearance of Him was promised to those disciples living in the 1st century AD.

Who was Jesus speaking to on the Mt of Olives?  His disciples.  What is the antecedent for the pronoun "ye" in Matt. 24:33?  Jesus was answering the question the disciples had asked Him in vs. 3:

> *"And when he is sitting on the mount of the Olives, the disciples came near to him by himself, saying, `Tell us, when shall these be? and what [is] the sign of thy presence, and of the full end of the age?'"*  (YLT)

Keep the scriptures in context.  Jesus was speaking to His disciples on the Mt. of Olives, and the pronoun "ye" referred to the disciples sitting with Him on the Mt. of Olives in approx. AD 30.

Not every "you" in the New Testament means "me" when we are reading them today, in our generation. (1)  The words "this generation" in Matt. 24:34 is not our generation today when we are reading the scriptures.  The pronoun "this" referred to their generation at the time Jesus was speaking to His disciples in AD 30.

It was His disciples and all those believers of that generation that was going to see His second appearance (Heb. 9:27) in judgment against those who had conspired to crucify Him (Rev. 1:7).  No other generation could have a second appearance of Him, as no other generation than that of the 1st cent. AD saw His first appearance of His manifestation on earth (1 Pet. 1:20).

Our generation, not our fathers, nor our grandfathers, nor great grandfathers, etc. never saw His manifestation on this earth.  It was the disciples of that 1st cent. AD generation who spoke with Him, saw Him, and touched Him that saw His second appearance.

The future tense verbs used throughout the New Testament prophesies were pointing to an event in THEIR generation, THEIR future. The prophesies were of the destruction of Jerusalem and that animal sacrificial temple which became profane once Christ became the Lamb sacrificed from the foundation of the world (Rev. 13:8), the last blood sacrifice YHWH would ever again accept for forgiveness of sins.  That temple was destroyed in AD 70 which occurred after the books of the NT were written, in their future lifetimes.

It is a past event for us.  Jesus rules the nations now with a rod of iron (Rev. 2:27; 12:5; 19:15).  His reign in His everlasting kingdom is one which has no end, and is over all the nations of this earth.  His reign includes His times of judgment of the nations, and each of those judgments would be a 3rd, or 4th, or 6th, or 12th coming of the Lord, as every judgment day of God in the prophesies was called a coming of the Lord, or a day of the Lord, or a day of their calamity, etc.

There is no telling how many other days of judgment God has pronounced from His heavenly throne since that 2nd coming in AD 70.  We should not be putting a limit on His judgment days of wicked men on this earth.

Note:

1. When Does "You" mean "Me" - [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/04/20/when-does-you-mean-me/)

Comment: The eschatological discourse in the synoptic gospels covers both the destruction of Jerusalem and the Temple in 70 AD and Jesus' Second Coming (Parousia in 2 Thess) at the end of times. Moreover, the destruction of Jerusalem and the Temple by the Roman army did not involve any second appearance of Jesus.

Comment: @Johannes - Yes, the coming of the Lord is a day of judgment, and that is what Jesus said He would do in Matt 25 at the destruction of that temple.  The disciples knew He was coming in judgment, and in glory, and that is always referred to as an appearance of the Lord, a day of vengeance, a day of their calamity, a day of wrath, etc.  Some translations - come a second time, return, etc.  The coming of the Lord was seen in the results of the judgment carried out.  Rev. 1:7, "Lo, he doth come with the clouds, and see him shall every eye, even those who did pierce him,..." - 1st cent. AD -

Comment: You are mixing notions. When Jerusalem fell to the Roman army Jesus did not come with the clouds and no eye saw Him.  It is at his Second Coming in glory when He will come with the clouds and every eye shall see Him.  Then the dead will be raised and all human beings  - the still living and the risen dead - will be judged publicly, individually and explicitely.

Comment: Are you sure?  Were you there?  This is classic institutional church dogma.  There are accounts that speak of armies seen in the clouds before the destruction of the temple (Josephus).  https://vridar.org/2020/01/14/miracles-with-multiple-jewish-and-roman-eyewitnesses/   You must let go of that literalist teaching.  Pls read the posts at my blog:  https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/01/24/testing-the-spirits-part-ii-the-end/ & https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/02/12/testing-the-spirits-part-iii-daniels-lot/

Answer (score 0):

**Master Teacher** The one with the final word on this subject, and who knows this topic the best is, of course, the Lord Jesus Christ.  And He has not remained silent on this matter, but spoke in clear, unmistakable terms:

*But of that Day and Hour (Second Coming) knoweth no man, no not the angels of heaven, (nor the Son, some manuscripts), but my Father only.* (Matthew 24:36)

*It is not for you to know the times or the seasons which the Father hath put in His own power.* (Acts 1:7)

There are **no signs** which are to reveal either "the day or hour" or "the times and seasons." This is clear. And any difficult verse about prophecy must fall under these two verse guidelines. They cannot be allowed to present an interpretation to the contrary.

But many still persist in coming up with "signs of the end-times." Some even eviscerate Jesus's words by saying "there are no signs, **but** normal times will cause people to be apathetic and given to lethargy, and this is a "sign" of the End!
Signs keep sneaking in.

The history of the last two thousand years has been replete with men who are assured they know the Signs of the Times of the End...and of course, it just happens to be in their day. So they gather a following of disciples...and **every single one of them has proven false!** The success rate of sign folk is *absolute zero*.

Why is this continual exploitation possible, year after year? D. James McKeever surmised: *Two things that sell are fear and greed. If you want to make money, write a book about how to make money, write a book how to get rich off the coming famine or some other disaster.  You'll sell a ton of copies because you have both the fear and the greed.*

*I think some ministries take advantage of the fact that people will pay money to get scared to death--like paying to go on a roller coaster or to see a horror movie.  Christians who don't go to movies and don't ride roller coasters possibly look at these teachers of prophecy to keep them scared to death.  I hate to say it, but they get a thrill out of it, just as they would from the roller coaster.* (p. 90 Soothsayers of the Second Advent)

To be sure, many congregates honestly want to genuinely know if there are signs, and if Christ is soon to return. They are **not tau** the words of Jesus about "no signs" so they become easily exploited. And when all the prophetic interpretations don't turn out to be true, they just go quietly away, embarrassed to talk about the disappointments. And the next generation sees the same thing all over again, ignorant of the many past failures, they become more pawns by prophecy preachers. The deceit is facilitated by the fact that the preacher is their pastoring "Man of God" who is too holy to deceive them...they surmise.

**The Main Tragedy** in all of this is that all the energy (worry, anxiety), and all the financial resources, and all the personnel, that go into propagating and supporting these false movements...could have gone instead into what is on the heart of Jesus the most: evangelism and discipleship of lost souls! The Gospel of Salvation with the Christmas coming, Crucifixion, Coronation, and unheralded Coming again is so simple, and so much needed for a lost and dying world...without the trappings of speculation and exploitation!

For in depth info see, Robert Clouse, et al. THE NEW MILLENNIUM MANUAL